# how to uninstall php compiled by source from mac os x mavericks

Tags: php, macos

Recently, I wanted to upgrade my php on a mac from 5.4 to 5.5 [latest version], I did it successful with the php-osx's [http://php-osx.liip.ch/] one Line installation.

But however in the terminal when I did `php -v`, I could see the older version, then tried to uninstall php installed by phposx following their uninstall method.

Later I felt that I had to compile php from the source. I headed to php.net and downloaded 5.5, `tar -zxvf`, `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

Now i feel like i'm going crazy as I have the older version when I issue `php -v`, also in the `/usr/local/bin/php -v` is the 5.5 version, and some packages installed with php-osx still available.

I need help with uninstalling the php compiled from source, and also totally remove some packages that where installed with php-osx, so that i just again install that latest version from the one line installer of `php-osx` and then just symlink it.

Thanks in advance!